# Serialize Dataset in readonly xml file

Tags: c#, file-io, xml-serialization

i have a `DataSet` which i am serializing in a `xml` file in encrypted mode.
currently following [srinivasganaparthi](http://srinivasganaparthi.blogspot.in/search/label/C-Sharp) to create a `xml` in encrypted mode. i also want to make file as read-only file. to achieve this. i am trying this:

```
public static void EncryptAndSerialize(Object obj)
{
    UnicodeEncoding aUE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] key = aUE.GetBytes("password");
    RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"D:\Sample.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key,   key), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            xmlser.Serialize(cs, obj);
        }
        fs.Close();
        File.SetAttributes(@"D:\Sample.xml",FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
}
```

But `File.SetAttributes` seems not working. how i can make this readonly?

Comment: try to set attributes after all usings

Comment: its same, after moving it from `using` section